# QGraphicsTextItem dropEvent not being called

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a subclassed QGraphicsTextItem class that acts as a label, which has a list of a different subclassed QGraphicsTextItem and these ones act as bullets/rows associated with the other class. I've implemented mouseMoveEvent and dropEvents for the label class and they work fine (basically it just swaps the labels and all bullets/rows associated with each). But I also want to implement this same feature but for swapping an individual bullet.

So I went ahead and implemented the dropEvent and mouseMoveEvent for the bullet class as well. When I drag the bullet class I see the mouseMoveEvent triggering, but when I drop it on another bullet class no dropEvent is called. I can drop it on the label class and notice that the label class's dropEvent is called (in this case I wouldn't want to do anything though), but no dropEvent is called when I drop a bullet on a bullet.

I've made sure that I have called the setAcceptDrops(true) in both classes and the flags for ItemIsMovable.

Comment: Please post a self-contained test case. So far, for anyone to help you out, they'd need to write such a test case themselves.

Comment: I think I've figured out what is happening. The size of my bullet QGraphicsTextItem is 0. If it were a widget I could do setMinimumSize, but graphics items don't have that function so I need to figure out a different way to force the size or maybe bounding rectangle rendered in the scene so it is large enough to accept a drop.